# Change request environment variables in Rails integration testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, integration-testing

I have written a functional test that changes some of the request object's environment variables to simulate a user has logged in.

```
require 'test_helper'
class BeesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  # See that the index page gets called correctly.
  def test_get_index

    @request.env['HTTPS'] = "on"
    @request.env['SERVER_NAME'] = "sandbox.example.com"
    @request.env['REMOTE_USER'] = "joeuser" # Authn/Authz done via REMOTE_USER

    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil(assigns(:bees))
    assert_select "title", "Bees and Honey"
  end
end
```

The functional test works fine.

Now I want to do something similar as part of integration testing. Here is what I tried:

```
require 'test_helper'
class CreateBeeTest < ActionController::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :bees

  def test_create
    @request.env['HTTPS'] = "on"
    @request.env['SERVER_NAME'] = "sandbox.example.com"
    @request.env['REMOTE_USER'] = "joeuser" # Authn/Authz done via REMOTE_USER

    https?

    get "/"
    assert_response :success
    [... more ...]
  end
end
```

I get an error complaining that `@request` is nil. I suspect this has something to do with the session object, but I am not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: The line `@request.env['HTTPS'] = "on"` complains that you cannot apply the `env` method to a nil value.

Comment: Here is a three-year old patch submission to Rails that addresses this issue: http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/8209

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set HTTPS in integration tests with

```
https!
```

And set the host name with:

```
host! "sandbox.example.com"
```

Which may be equivalent to what you want to do?

This is described in the Rails guides [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#helpers-available-for-integration-tests)

Comment: But how to set for example `request.remote_ip`? There is no similar special method for that in `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session`

Comment: I also got here looking for a way yo set `request.remote_ip`, it worked for me using the env params like this: `get "/", params: params, env: { 'REMOTE_ADDR' => '1.2.3.4' }`

Answer (score 1):

You can change request variables via parameters to post method.

For your case, method *test_create* will be:

```
def test_create
  https!

  get "/", nil, { 'SERVER_NAME'] => "sandbox.example.com", 'REMOTE_USER'] => "joeuser" }

  assert_response :success
  [... more ...]
end
```

Same works for setting post request to raw data:

```
post root_path, nil, { 'RAW_POST_DATA' => 'some string' }
```